# WPF - Hide minimize button of a window

Tags: wpf, window, minimize

In WPF, how can I hide the minimize button (only the minimize, not also the maximize...) of a window.

The code in this forum almost work for me. The behavior of that code is that it's disabled the minimize button. But, how hide it?

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/222067/532926.aspx

Comment: As Bolu points out, you'd have to render your own window chrome. Windows will only hide the minimize/maximize buttons as a group. So even with the Win32 API you can't hide only the minimize button. You can disable it, but that's separate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you would have to hide the default window title and draw your own titlebar.

e.g.: [C# WPF Custom Title Bar Tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/121576-c#-wpf-custom-title-bar-tutorial/)
and [Moving a WPF Window with Custom Chrome](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/02/01/moving-a-wpf-window-with-custom-chrome)

Comment: I opened an issue for voting in the WPF github repository to add more control over these buttons: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/4294

Answer (score 15):

How about disabling the resize attribute?

```
ResizeMode="NoResize"
```

Comment: This is the easiest answer!

Comment: That doesn't do *just* what the OP asked for, if just removing the minimize/maximize buttons.  It also turns off the ability to resize the window by dragging from the sides/corners.

Comment: I opened an issue for voting in the WPF github repository to add more control over these buttons: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/4294